# Customizing the Cells in the DatePicker in GWT

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I was looking to customize the cells in the GWT DatePicker widget. By that I mean instead of showing only the date such as: "1" for the first day of the month, I want to display "1 (My Birthday)" or any other information in the parentheses. (I want the info to be rendered dynamically).

I tried creating my own CalendarView to do so but that was extremely complicated. Is there any other way that you know to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't receive a response for a while and assumed that there is no other way to do so. In order to implement what I needed, I created my own custom CalendarView that closely resembled the `DefaulCalendarView` class. After doing so I added functionality to it and can now display anything on the cells.